# добавление в массив пары ключ:значения SWIFT 3.0

Tags: массивы, swift3

SWIFT 3.0

```
var array: [String: Any] = [:]
array = ["123":["colorID": "COunt", "234": "6666"]]
```

как добавить в array["123"] ключ со знаением ?
   array["123"]["ключ"] = "значение" так не получается
**Error: Type Any? has no subscript members**

Answer (score 0):

Добавить можно так:

```
var array : [String : Any] = [:]
array["123"] = ["test": 123, "tttest": 321]
```

А вообще, для решения подобных синтаксических вопросов очень удобно использовать Playground в XCode.